# No defined language in my drupal node

Tags: drupal, undefined

I have a problem with my nodes in Drupal 7. I have set the default language to french, activated the translations for the content (with modules and content types).
I would like to access to the fields of my node like this : $node->field_image['fr'][...].
The problem is that the language is not defined and the fields look like $node->field_image['und'][...].

Can anyone help me? Thanks

Here is the print_r() of the body of the node :

```
[body] => Array
    (
    [und] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
        (
            [value] => Pid magna et amet augue[...]
        )
    )
)
```